# State pattern in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, state-pattern

I've read about state pattern and now I'm looking to further my knowledge by exploring a Swing application (exple : calculator) that implements it.

where can I find such a tutorial ?

it must showcase a really simple application that uses Swing. I'm confused about how the State Pattern could be used in a Swing project ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I really don't think that a calculator application is a good match for State pattern. A simple calculator does not have too many states, maybe on/off but that's too trivial. A drawing tool is a better match.

If you really want to develop a calculator based on the state pattern you really need to be quite creative. But why not? You could invent/implement a calculator where the basic operations (addition, substraction, multiplication, division) are modes (states):

```
public enum Modes {ADDITION, SUBTRACTION, MULITPLICATION, DIVISION}

public interface Mode {
  double calculate(double a, double b);
}

public class AdditionMode implements Mode {
  public double calculate(double a, double b) {
    return (a+b);
  }
}
// similiar classes for other math operation modes

public class Calculator {
  private Mode mode;
  public setMode(Modes mode) {
    switch (mode) {
      case ADDITION: this.mode = new AdditionMode();
      // ...
    }
  }
  public double calculate(double a, double b) {
    return mode.calculate(a, b);
  }
}
```

This is a very simple and basic draft and, of course, doesn't cover the View part (Swing dialog or whatever). On the dialog you could use four radio buttons to set the modes, a text field to capture input and a text field or label to print the actual result.

Comment: thx 4 the reply. what i'd really like is to see how to do that in the presence of Swing dialog. I've done something but I'm not sure wether my code follows good standards, that's why i wanna look at somebody else's code.

Answer (score 3):

A sample you find [here](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=java&seqNum=576)

I used this pattern in a swing application to represent a selected a drawing tool (line,polygon, etc.).

A full application that uses the state pattern in this way is [JHotDraw](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jhotdraw/)

EDIT: For a calculator it could be used to map keystrokes (entered digits and operators) in calculation mode (== state) and in graph drawing mode (2nd state) for zoom and movement of the displayed graph.

To represent a mode like DEG, RAD, and GRA (degrees,radians) you shouldn't use the state pattern. This would be over engineered.

Comment: hi stacker, thanks for JHotDraw, but i feel like it's too much for what i want. i'd like something simple like a calculator.